# Javascript return returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, json

The function is working fine. It sends the request to the php file and gets back the right response. I knew this when I use alert function right after assigning xhr.responseText to products variable. However, return function isn't returning products variable at all. When I alert products after the return function, it gives me no response at all.

```
var api_fetch_input = document.querySelector('.api_fetch_input');
var api_fetch_list = document.querySelector('.api_fetch_input').nextElementSibling;
var index = 0;
var items = 0;
// Fetch Products
function fetch_api_products(query) {
    var products = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            products = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    var url = 'products.php?act=search_products&query=' + query;
    url = encodeURI(url);
    xhr.open('GET', url , false);
    xhr.send();
    items = products.length;
    return products;
```

In the console window it gives me this error though

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
at fetch_api_products (pos.php?act=q_sale&customer_id=1932&u_key=a45a6dc5:7149:26)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (pos.php?act=q_sale&customer_id=1932&u_key=a45a6dc5:7189:28)
```

This is my PHP code

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . @$config['db_server'] . ';dbname=' . @$config['db_name'], @$config['db_user'], @$config['db_password']);
        $dbh->exec("set names utf8mb4");

        if(isset($_GET['query'])){
            $query  = $_GET['query'];
            $stmt   = "SELECT id,name,barcode,price FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR barcode LIKE '%" . $query . "%'";
            echo json_encode($dbh->query($stmt)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        }
```

Please take into consideration that I'm an AB JS learner. Any help please?

Thank you

Comment: "nothing" doesn't make sense in Javascript, what does really give you? null, undefined, an empty string or something else? You only assign `products` when readyState is 4 and status is 200, are you sure all the conditions have been met? 
XHR is not executed synchronously, accessing `products` right after `send` is wrong.

Comment: Your xmlhttprequest is asynchronous.  You may not return the response, because the return happens before the response is received.  You should “do stuff” with products inside the readystatechange handler.  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: In the console it gives me this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at fetch_api_products (pos.php?act=q_sale&customer_id=1932&u_key=a45a6dc5:7149:26)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (pos.php?act=q_sale&customer_id=1932&u_key=a45a6dc5:7189:28)

Comment: `code`$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . @$config['db_server'] . ';dbname=' . @$config['db_name'], @$config['db_user'], @$config['db_password']);
            $dbh->exec("set names utf8mb4");

            if(isset($_GET['query'])){
                $query  = $_GET['query'];
                $stmt   = "SELECT id,name,barcode,price FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR barcode LIKE '%" . $query . "%'";
                echo json_encode($dbh->query($stmt)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            }`code`

Comment: @Hakeem if you have extra information to share with us please [edit] your question properly. As you can see, code in the comments is very hard to read, and it's also hidden away from the rest of your post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about asynchronous operation. The problems is that, when the function is run to 'return products', the api results is not back immediately(the program wont wait). So you got null.

`Promise` object might help. Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises. and learn more about `Promise` or other asynchronous solution.